# Google Sheets, my importxml formula suddenly broke

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

a little question because for a few days, my formula based on importxml is broken, without that, I have not made any changes to my website.

I obviously have a problem XPath that can not extract information in the body of my articles.

I can extract elements of the header but not the body, even something very simple like my h1.

If someone would have a track

my formula (broken):

```
= ImportXML ( "https://piao.fr/2019/10/une-nouvelle-offre-de-mobilite-reduite-avec-tao/","//h1 [1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://piao.fr/2019/10/une-nouvelle-offre-de-mobilite-reduite-avec-tao/"), 500, 3), 
 "select Col3 where Col3 contains '<h1'"), "headline"">(.+)</h1")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Woaaaa that's work perfect ! Thanks you. But i can't understand why it's so complicated now.

Comment: now (using importdata) its scrapped directly from source code